# can't get location on iOS - doesn't call delegate methods

Tags: ios, delegates, location, locationmanager

i have a problem with the locationManager under iOS 6.

```
-(void) getLocationTest {
// Create a location manager instance to determine if location services are enabled. This manager instance will be
// immediately released afterwards.

manager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
if (![manager locationServicesEnabled]) {
    UIAlertView *servicesDisabledAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Location Services Disabled" message:@"You currently have all location services for this device disabled. If you proceed, you will be asked to confirm whether location services should be reenabled." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [servicesDisabledAlert show];
    //[servicesDisabledAlert release];
}
manager.delegate = self;
manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer;
// Set a movement threshold for new events.
manager.distanceFilter = 500;
[manager startUpdatingLocation];

//[manager release];
}





-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
double testDe = 2.434;
testDe = testDe * 2;
}



-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
 didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
CLLocation *location = [locations objectAtIndex:0];
double locDouble = location.coordinate.latitude;
NSString* locName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Hello, %f!", locDouble];
//[locations lastObject];
//NSLog(@"lat%f - lon%f", location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude);
}


-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
double testD = 2.434;
testD = testD * 2;
}
```

i have breakpoints in all the delegate methods, but none of them is being called.
Does someone know what i'm doing wrong? or how i can find out where the error is?

i would be grateful for every answer!
thanks!

Comment: Does the app use ARC?  Is `manager` declared as a strong property?

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing this on a device or in the simulator? In the simulator you have to manually set some location from the simulator app menu. It's in Debug/Location/.

Comment: thanks for this hint. but i activated location for debug and simulator tells me that he has location by this little gps sign right on the top.

and further i think that if he had no location found that he has to jump in the didFailWithError delegate at least?

Comment: Okay then, so as Anna Karenina already asked, is manager a strong property? Maybe it gets deallocated. Is the -(void)getLocationTest method called?

Comment: oh sorry, haven't seen this. ARC is enabled. is this good or bad?
and i tried weak and strong property, but didn't help.
the -(void)getLocationTest method is called and works... :/

Comment: @Mex, Keep manager a `strong` property and in getLocationTest, try changing the alloc+init to: `self.manager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];` (put `self.` in front).